# IVI-COM Driver C# How to change serial port configuration before calling Initialize method?

Tags: c#

I'm using IVI-COM driver for E3634A in C#.
I connect the device with a Serial RS232 cable. When I call

```cs
AgilentE36xx driver = new AgilentE36xx();
driver.Initialize("ASRL3::INSTR", false, false);
```

the IVI driver use default settings for COM3 port. But I want to set StopBits to 2 (rather than default value of 1).
How can I set serial port setting before calling Initialize method?

Comment: I would leave as is.  One stop bit will always work with two stop bits.  Using two stop bits will fail if device is only using one stop bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set Com port's default, I should use "kernel32" windows assembly using "DLLImport" attribute in C#.
The function is "SetDefaultCommConfigW".